# JUnit - Best practices of testing bean validation with data sets

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, bean-validation

I want to write unit test, which verifies correct configuration of bean validation constraints. I believe that test should be made on set of data, so it verifies many different combinations.

So far I made this code:

```java
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class TagTest {

    private Validator validator;

    @Parameterized.Parameter
    public Pair<Boolean, Tag> tagPair;

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Pair<Boolean, Tag>> testData() {

        Collection<Pair<Boolean, Tag>> tags = new ArrayList<>();

        Tag tag = new Tag();
        tag.setId(1L);
        tag.setVersion(1L);
        tag.setTitle("Sample");
        tags.add(new ImmutablePair<>(true, tag));

        // ... more sample data

        return tags;
    }

    @Before
    public void init() {
        ValidatorFactory vf = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        this.validator = vf.getValidator();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldBeValidated() {        
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Tag>> violations = validator.validate(
                tagPair.getRight());

        Assert.assertTrue(violations.isEmpty() == tagPair.getLeft());
    }  
}
```

What would be best solution to read sample data from? Holding data in a code doesn't seem pretty to me. Tag in my example is flat object. What if object would be complex?

Is it acceptable for unit test, that I would make general test for bean validation, which would accept `Object` (instead of `Tag` in my case) and then validate whatever data I would push in it?

Comment: You could shorten things quite a bit by providing a constructor for `Tag` that includes all the members, so you don't need to call setter methods. You might also consider using JUnitParams as your runner, since it has much better features compared to the built-in parameterized runner.

Comment: To providing constructor for Tag is not general solution. What about entities with a lot of properties? JUnitParams seems promising.

Comment: If you have a model that's so complex that you can't use constructors, your model might well be wrong, or your tests might not be sufficiently narrow. Otherwise, you're going to need a way to serialize all your test inputs and build a custom deserializer that you can use to wire up a parameterized test suite.

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep things simpler. E.g. try to keep test data close to the test logic. There are 2 more or less good ways to achieve what you need:

- Use TestNG and its `@DataProvider`
- Use JUnit and keep many tests in one test. While usually the best practice is to separate tests into different test methods for validation I think you can violate this rule. This is because there are too many validation tests and they are very simple (see example below).

You can also turn to other frameworks like Spock that provide best of the breed data providers, but they are usually written in dynamic languages (like Groovy) which would bring more harm than good.

Another alternative of course is using `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)`. But this is a very weird mechanism and I haven't seen anyone using it in real life because of how inconvenient it is. You can also take a look at `@Theory`.

Here is a real life example with JUnit:

```
@Test public void validationMustPass_forValidExperimentName() {
    assertExperimentNameValidationPasses("Min boundary", alphanumeric(1));
    assertExperimentNameValidationPasses("Max boundary", alphanumeric(20));
    assertExperimentNameValidationPasses("With all alphanumerics and allowed special characters",
            between(2, 19).with(multipleOf("_-")).alphanumeric());
    assertExperimentNameValidationPasses("With spaces", between(2, 19).with(oneOf(" ")).alphanumeric());
    assertExperimentNameValidationPasses("Only numbers", between(2, 19).numeric());
    assertExperimentNameValidationPasses("Only dashes", between(2, 19).string('-'));
    assertExperimentNameValidationPasses("Only underscores", between(2, 19).string('_'));
}

@Test public void mustNotCreateExperimentWithWrongExperimentName() {
    assertExperimentNameValidationFails(
            "Longer than max allowed length",
            "Should be between 1 and 20 symbols.",
            length(21).alphanumeric());
    assertExperimentNameValidationFails("Experiment name is white space",
            "Should be between 1 and 20 symbols.",
            "  ");
    assertExperimentNameValidationFails("Experiment name is empty",
            "Should be between 1 and 20 symbols.",
            "");
    assertExperimentNameValidationFails("Experiment name contains not allowed symbols",
            "Only English letters, numbers, spaces, dashes and underscores are allowed",
            length(10).with(oneOf(FORBIDDEN_CHARACTERS)).alphanumeric());
}
```

And that's just for 1 field of the object. Here is an example of [doing this with Spock](http://qala.io/blog/test-pyramid.html), but as I've mentioned - it usually is not worth it. And here are some basic rules to [keep data management effective](http://qala.io/blog/test-data-management.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It doesn't really solve my problem, but your links to articles have very good points. I found out, that keyword for what I need here is data-driven test. I don't want to test each constraint, but if validation constraints are correctly put on entity.